# Pushing revisions of a single file via git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am developing a small project in git: it is actually a single XML file plus a couple of scripts for testing purposes. I need to submit that XML file to a third party who keeps a several such XML files (no scripts) in an SVN repo.

Is it possible (and how) to setup git-svn so that I could push new revisions of that single XML file to the SVN repo, but discarding the script files I have in git? I sill want to have the scripts version-controlled in git.

Answer (score 0):

Discarding your script files is simple - just define them in `.git/info/exlcude`. More usual `.gitignore` will probably not be good for you as you don't want it to land on the SVN.

Comment: I still want the scripts version-controlled.

Comment: Fair enough. That won't probably be straightforward unless you are ok with having scripts in different repo/directory.